# How create a combobox on Python with GTK3?

Tags: python, gtk3

I have read [this manual](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/combobox.html#Gtk.ComboBox) to create a simple combo-box with strings:

But when I start my application I get this message:

```
(button.py:7646): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed
```

And the combo box appears but the item (the only item I'm adding) don't appears

This is my source:

```
class Ventana(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self,title="Test Window")
        paises=Gtk.ListStore(int,str)
        paises.append([1,"test"])

        combo=Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(paises)
        combo.set_active(0)
        self.add(combo)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the entry for combo by calling set_entry_text_column(column) instead of combo.set_active(0)

```
class Ventana(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self, title = "Test"):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self,title="Test Window")
        paises=Gtk.ListStore(int,str)
        paises.append([1,"test"])

         combo=Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model_and_entry(paises)
         combo.set_entry_text_column(1)
         self.add(combo)
```

See : http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/combobox.html?highlight=set_entry_text_column

Comment: Thanks :) ! now, what about quit the entry? using just Gtk.ComboBox.new_with_model(paises) ?

Comment: Sorry for late. It seems it should also work but i have used neither python nor gtk for a long time so it'd be the best that you check docs and try :) You can also mark the answer correct if you think so..

Comment: I have read all night hahaha at last i found a way using cell renderers :) thanks !!