# Populating a Glade combobox "gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed"?

Tags: python, combobox, gtk, pygtk, glade

I am building a “pseudo-intelligent” GUI for a gimp plugin using Glade. The main part of the GUI has two frames and imports the contents using the “reparent” method. The main objective is to have the contents of the second frame determined by the selections made in the first frame. (Eventually, the intention is to import this GUI as the content for the tabbed pages of a "notebook")

To start with, I made a simple window, consisting of a “RadioButtonBox” and a “ComboBox” which is populated using:

```
# create the cell renderer
self.cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
#populate the default choice into the Selection  combobox
self.SelectionBox = self.builder.get_object("SelectionBox")
self.SelectionBox.set_model(self.EditCommands)
self.SelectionBox.pack_start(self.cell, True)
self.SelectionBox.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 1)
self.SelectionBox.set_active(0)
# End: populate the selection combo box section
```

This works and I can successfully “import” and “reparent” the simple GUI as the first frame of the larger, more complex GUI without any problems. However, as the design progressed, it has become more convenient to have the code for the first frame as an integral part of the main GUI, and this is where my problems begin.

I have reproduced the contents of the simple GUI in the first frame of the larger GUI and copy/pasted the code from the simple GUI's “**init**” function. In other-words, everything is identical.

Unfortunately, when I run the code I get the following error:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\anonymous\Desktop\Glade-tutorial\BatchEditMain\BatchEditLibrary\Tab.py:46: GtkWarning: gtk_entry_set_text: assertion `text != NULL' failed
  self.SelectionBox.set_active(0)
```

Could someone please explain what the problem is?

Thanks in advance

Irvine

Comment: Is `EditCommands` populated by that point?

Comment: Yes, though there is a  caveat: The spacing of the list  seems to be  offset,  so that the list is only visible in the drop down menu, not in the combobox itself.

Answer (score 0):

The GTK Warning is saying that somewhere `gtk_entry.set_text()` is being called with `None` instead of some text. This is happening in the call to `self.SelectionBox.set_active(0)`

Comment: Yes, that's the diagnosis, but that doesn't explain why it's doing that. There's nothing there that obviously uses GtkEntry (this is likely a GtkComboBox that has an entry), so more investigation is needed.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because we can't see the code for `SelectionBox`. I've explained the slightly cryptic warning message. It should be straightforward to then find the call to `gtk_entry.set_text()` and track down the problem. More information is required from the OP.

Comment: **1)** The same code works when the “combobox” is part of a simple GUI, and it continues to work when the simple GUI is  reparented as part of a more complex GUI. It only ceases to work when I build the functionality directly into the more complex GUI.  **2)** “SelectionBox” is a GTK/Glade object defined by the line 'self.SelectionBox = self.builder.get_object("SelectionBox")'  **3)** 'gtk_entry.set_text()' is not directly called by my function, but part of  the GTK.  As a result, any legitimate resolution of the problem should not involve tracking this function down.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite agree. `'gtk_entry.set_text()` is called by the GLADE object, which you have defined, not some obscure inner workings of GTK. Whether you think it's legitimate or not, if you want to fix your problem, you're going to have to find why this call is failing. What happens if you try to set a different default entry (e.g. `self.SelectionBox.set_active(1)`)? Can you dump the contents of `self.EditCommands`?

Answer (score 0):

This feels a little bit like gravedigging , but i stumbled across the same Problem today and this was the first post google showed...

With a little further research i found this Question:

[How create a combobox on Python with GTK3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897626/how-create-a-combobox-on-python-with-gtk3)
The author seems to have the same error.

What in his and my case seems to do the trick is a simple:

```
combobox.set_entry_text_column(0)
```

Important it has to be in front of `set_active(0)`!
So in your case this would be:

```
...
self.SelectionBox.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 1)
self.SelectionBox.set_entry_text_column(0)
self.SelectionBox.set_active(0)
...
```

PS: Whatch out if you want to apply attributes like "foreground", they seem to get overwritten by `set_entry_text_column(0)` if set befor.
E.g: if items in the model look like:

```
["TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_DISPLAY","TEXT_FOREGROUNDCOLOR_AS_MARKUP_COLOR"]
```

The change to the foregroundcolor can be applied with the following:

```
...
self.SelectionBox.add_attribute(self.cell, 'text', 0)
self.SelectionBox.set_entry_text_column(0)
self.SelectionBox.add_attribute(self.cell, 'foreground', 1)
self.SelectionBox.set_active(0)
...
```